# How to merge detached HEAD conflict fixes with original branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge-conflict

I had a really out of date `sales-refactor` branch that I wanted to sync with my master branch. I use bitbucket, and when I go to my `sales-refactor` branch, I click on Sync Now and it tells me that "This merge has conflicts that must be resolved before it can be committed."

It also gives me some commands I need to run to fix my conflicts (which I did), but now I don't know what to do next to keep my changes that fixed the conflicts (lots of conflicts) into my `sales-refactor` branch.

I ran these commands following bitbucket's instructions:

```
git checkout e17ba371fdf3
# Note: This will create a detached head!
git merge remotes/origin/master
```

Now, I'm on `HEAD detached from e17ba371)`, and I need to get these changes to my `sales-refactor` branch and push it to my repo.

Can anyone help? I'm not sure exactly how to google for help on this one, so I figured I better give more details in a SO question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure to do a `git fetch`, to ensure `origin/master` is up-to-date in your local repo.

If you are sure your `git log` shows the correct history for sales-refactor, you can force push it

```
git push --force origin @:sales-refactor
```

But it is better to reset your local branch first:

```
git branch -f sales-refactor @
```

Then force push it:

```
git checkout sales-refactor
git push -f
```

Comment: ok, I got lost... so, first, I do `git branch -f sales-refactor @`, then `git checkout sales-refactor` and then `git push -f`? will that take whatever I have in my detached head into my sales-refactor branch?

Comment: @andrux yes: you detached head is currently referenced by @ (HEAD): reset your branch to it, checkout said reset branch, and force push it. Check your git log first.